# Model FineTuning Error: ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits,past_key_values

Tags: huggingface-transformers, gpt-3, fine-tuning

Trying to finetune/train a GPTneo model:

### Error Message

ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits,past_key_values. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask.

### Code

```
### Tokenize function ###
def tokenize(x: dict, max_length: int = 1024) -> dict:
    """
    For a dictionary example of instruction, response, and context a dictionary of input_id and attention mask is returned
    """
    instr = x["instruction"]
    resp = x["response"]
    context = x["context"]

    instr_part = f"### Instruction:\n{instr}"
    context_part = ""
    if context:
        context_part = f"\nInput:\n{context}\n"
    resp_part = f"### Response:\n{resp}"

    text = f"""Below is an instruction that describes a task. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.

{instr_part}
{context_part}
{resp_part}

### End
"""
    return mhtokenizer(text, max_length=max_length, truncation=True)
```

#### Call Tokenizer

```
tokenized_data=ds.map(tokenize,remove_columns=["instruction", "response", "context", "category"] )
```

#### Prepare Data

```
TRAINING_SIZE=6000
SEED=42
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=mhtokenizer, mlm=False, return_tensors="pt", pad_to_multiple_of=8
)
#split_dataset_mh = interim_tokenized_dataset.train_test_split(train_size=6000, seed=42)

tokenized_data
split_dataset = tokenized_data["train"].train_test_split(train_size=6000, seed=42)
```

#### Prepare Training

````
training_args = tr.TrainingArguments(
    local_checkpoint_path,
    num_train_epochs=1,  # default number of epochs to train is 3
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    optim="adamw_torch",
    report_to=["tensorboard"],
)

model_checkpoint = "EleutherAI/pythia-70m-deduped"
tokenizer = tr.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
model_checkpoint,
revision="step3000"
)

model = tr.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained (
model_checkpoint)
data_collator = tr.DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)
trainer = tr.Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=split_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=split_dataset["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
)
trainer.train()

```
````

the train function should work. Not sure what columns its expecting as input ids'

### Full Traceback

```
***** Running training *****
  Num examples = 6000
  Num Epochs = 1
  Instantaneous batch size per device = 8
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 8
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
  Total optimization steps = 750
  Number of trainable parameters = 70426624
You're using a GPTNeoXTokenizerFast tokenizer. Please note that with a fast tokenizer, using the `__call__` method is faster than using a method to encode the text followed by a call to the `pad` method to get a padded encoding.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Documents/Training&Education/DataBricksLLM/LLM 04 - Fine-tuning and Evaluating LLMs/untitled0.py:129
    trainer.train()

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1501 in train
    return inner_training_loop(

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1749 in _inner_training_loop
    tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2508 in training_step
    loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2553 in compute_loss
    raise ValueError(

    ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits,past_key_values. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask.
```